# Creating Siebel workflow policy

Tags: workflow, siebel

I'm trying to create Siebel workflow for a new business requirement, I've checked Siebel Bookshelf and I'm bit confused with the flow. Especially I'm having difficulty in understanding the relationship between Workflow policy object, Workflow policy column, workflow policy component, workflow policy component col and how database triggers are created.

Can someone help me to understand these concepts better?

Comment: Have you read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/BPFWorkflow/using_predefined_policies3.html)? See also [this](http://siebeldev.blogspot.ru/2010/04/workflow-policies-vs-workflow-processes.html) and [that](http://siebelenhance.blogspot.ru/2013/03/how-siebel-workflow-policy-works.html) useful articles. And [one more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/BPFWorkflow/administering_policies4.html#wp1137746) about trigger generation. If you have read this all and still have questions then please list your specific troubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workflow policy objects and components are very much like the business logic layer objects and components that support the Siebel GUI. A Workflow policy object might be Account, and its components could be Account, Account Contact, Account Address, etc.

Workflow policies themselves are still (I think) created in the Siebel GUI on the server. If your policy conditions are based on a custom field, you might have to add this to the workflow policy component involved using Siebel Tools.

The columns are the set of fields that the triggers are generated for and that Siebel workflow policy will be referenced against. The Siebel monitor components wake up when the trigger is fired, check the policy conditions, and then run whatever processes are attached to the policy.

Once the policy is defined, the generate triggers command needs to be called against the database to include the new trigger details your policy has created. This can be done using Siebel server manager or using SQL directly against the database. Check the Siebel Business Process Framework: Workflow Guide for more details on these steps and how to validate you work.